# Texture is not rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing

I have quite a bit of experience with blender and this is the first time I've run into troubles with texturing.

Quite simply, I have a mesh that I have UVmapped in the same way I always do, but no matter what I do, I can't get a texture to stick on it.

It shows up perfectly in the viewport, but not in the preview- or final render.

If I make another mesh, like a standard cube, with the same material, that mesh gets the texture just like normal.

.blend file included, along with a screenshot that shows everything I've just said.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/geb0vxlmbqzk1ef/amaryllis.blend?dl=0

[image: blender screen shot]

Comment: texture not found. from the screenshot, you're using the alpha chanel as factor, is it a choice or the problem?

Comment: Yes, I *just now* realized I hadn't included the texture!
here it is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nzplzstmpk8yff6/amaryllis%20tex.png?dl=0

But yes, it's supposed to be an alpha channel mask.
I've done this so many times before that it's almost embarrasing to ask about it now :P

EDIT: Also! no image-based textures whatsoever stick to the mesh, alpha or not!

Comment: Are you questioning the curved plane on the right? Because I do not see a problem with the other two meshes' materials.

Comment: Yes, it was the leaf mesh to the right that I was having troubles with, but that problem is now solved below :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have experimental subdivision enabled in *Properties > Object data*:

[image]

It appears that it does not yet support UV maps, hence the experimental part..

Comment: Thank you! 
I hadn't any idea that an experimeltal feature could have such an impact!

And I didn't even realize that that specific subdivision function was an experimental one, but now I know! 

Yay!

Answer (score 2):

The texture works as soon as you change the render Feature Set to Supported from Experimental. I don't know what current experimental feature is breaking it, but at least you know you aren't doing something else wrong.

Comment: You seem to have hit the nail, and the person below you has hit it even further! It does in fact seem I'm using an experimental feature that doesn't support image mapping! thanks! I'll give your answer a point as soon as I'm allowed to :)